# Firefox addon element abnormally flashing using CSS animation on Mac

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The problem only happens on Mac:

The 'Test Link' element flashes abnormally when used in a Firefox addon panel (sdk/panel) when compared to the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sozvga4g/1/) despite they share the same source code.

Firefox addon source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHBWuszZv5_eWl1RTdIOW84NG8/view?usp=sharing

to run

download and unzip

`$ cd CSSFlashing3; cfx run`

Is there any workaround to the problem because who knows how long does it take for Mozilla to fix this?

Comment: I have ran into this problem as well (except in the XUL code, HTML scope seems to work fine for me), thaks for bringing it back to my attention. I filed this on bugzilla for you thanks for writing up the test case: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175884 also if you used github instead of google drive it would be better

Comment: Here's a screencast of my flashing issue, it triggers the mousleave even which causes my expanded menu to collapse, this is undesired behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEeGAjhhntw